# Why does my Angular $http get request return my index.html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

```
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myApp.controllers'])

    .config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'app/views/myApp.html',
          controller: 'appController'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
```

---

```
  angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('appController', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.oneCharacter = function() {
        $http({
          method:'GET',
          url:'http://localhost:3000/#/api/info'
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log('-------------------------', response);
        }) .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }

    });
```

---

```
    <div ng-controller="appController">
      <input type="button" value="button" ng-click="oneCharacter()"/>


    </div>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="app/controllers/myApp.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Hello,
I am sending a get request to `http://localhost:3000/#/api/info` server which I build. I am expecting a `json` object full of peoples info back. However, every time I click the `button` in my `appController` (controller), the request does not go the specified `url`. Every time I get back the `index.html` content which I copied below. However, I have test it my server using `postman`, and it returns the correct info. Does anyone know why is that happening ?
Thanks

Comment: 'http://localhost:3000/#/api/info' is the same as 'http://localhost:3000/index.html#/api/info', you can try deploying your backed on a diferent port that your frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you're supplying to `$http` is

```
url:'http://localhost:3000/#/api/info'
```

The `#` means those are just hashes (aka: anchors) which is what Angular uses to do do internal routing. So what you're requesting is just `/` which is your `index.html` page.

Assuming you have a local server hosting your API, you'll need to remove the `#`.

```
url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/info'
```